# Nuxt change typescript version

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I created a new Nuxt app (`yarn create nuxt-app <app-name>`) with Typescript setting enabled.

The typescript errors when running through `nuxt dev` are more strict/different than if i run the same code through a normal `vue-cli-service` app.

Why would the same code give different typescript errors?

Is it the typescript version? Is there a way to specify or downgrade the Typescript version? I see there are a ton of errors in this project, whereas the original project I copied the files from didn't have any errors (TS version 4.4).

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    "@types/whatwg-fetch": "^0.0.33",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  }
```

Comment: Put a different version as you did for `typescript`basically? Not sure to understand the issue here.

Comment: @kissu maybe i'm asking the wrong question, but the errors when running through `nuxt dev` are more strict/different than if i run the same code through a normal `vue-cli-service` app

Comment: Probably because of a Nuxt specific ESlint rules.